# Can this JQuery be shorter writen?

Tags: jquery

I got this code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('tr.DataDark input[type=checkbox], tr.DataLight input[type=checkbox]').click(function () {
        $(this).closest('tr').toggleClass('Selected');
    });
    $('tr.DataDark input[type=checkbox]:checked, tr.DataLight input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function () {
        $(this).closest('tr').addClass('Selected');
    });
});
```

Can it be shorter written?

Thanks for suggestions.

Comment: I fixed your code to be properly indented in an edit and you whacked over the top of my edit to screw it up again.  Please learn how to format code on this site (a fundamental feature).  Highlight the code and use the `{}` button in the text editor and look at the preview window before you post.

Comment: First timer, my bad. I appreciate your work! Won't happen again.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question does not conform to the expected format : stackoverflow.com/faq#questions . You should ask help to solve a real issue, not how to do something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this? Not exactly shorter, but possibly simpler.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var checkBoxes = $('tr.DataDark input[type=checkbox], tr.DataLight input[type=checkbox]');

  checkBoxes.on("click", function() {
    $(this).closest('tr').toggleClass('Selected');
  });

  checkBoxes.filter(':checked').closest('tr').addClass('Selected');
});
```

To make it shorter you could forego the `checkBoxes` variable and chain the `filter().closest().addClass()` calls directly to `on("click")`.

Answer (score 0):

Without showing us the matching HTML so we might see what shortcuts are possible, there's no meaningful way to shorten the number of lines of code you have presented.

There are ways to change it or to minimize it to make it fewer characters or to collapse multiple lines into one longer line, but if you want to keep it readable and still carry out the same logic you have and not artificially collapse multiple pieces of logic together into a longer line, it will take about the number of lines of code you have.

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair - No, it's an answer to the question as asked with the information provided.  The answer is no.